# Microsoft Graph List places API support for US National cloud

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar, azure-gov

I am trying to use the following US National Cloud URL along with access token to list rooms as per this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

```
   https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=5000
   https://dod-graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=5000
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

However it works fine with global endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=5000`

Is List places API not supported with US endpoints or is there anything additional required to make the request? How do I find out if it is supported in US environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details about national cloud deployments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments).

Not all Graph features are available across all national clouds.

Before calling Graph API, you should first acquire a token from endpoint which is specific for each national cloud.

`Azure AD for US Government` cloud requires `https://login.microsoftonline.us` endpoint for acquiring the token.

Comment: The authentication is successful with https://login.microsoftonline.us and I am passing the acquired token to the List places request.